# jQuery $.ajax glitch, adding version string?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm not sure where this glitch is occurring.  I've tried checking the javascript, the browser console, and the server.  We're running jquery 1.8.3 and Django.

Here's a screen shot and description of the problem:

[image]

See the `name` key.  It's a post variable that is sent via ajax:

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    url: dataURL, 
    dataType: 'json'
};

if (postData) {
    ajaxOptions.type = "POST";
    ajaxOptions.data = postData;
}

var request = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

I've set `globalBuilderPost` to equal `postData` for the console (in the screenshot).

Before it's sent, `name` is `HUMAN POPULATION .....?????`, and Django receives it as `u'HUMAN POPULATION .....jQuery18306933938320726156_1375226489186???'`.

My question (I think obviously), is why is the jQuery string in that variable?

Sorry if I sound crazy (I honestly think I am going crazy).

### Edit (Possible, strange cause)

I meant to add what I see as the trigger for the problem: It seems like it replaces double question marks: `??`

Comment: Try sending data in the form `data: {'data': postdata }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have hit this jQuery bug

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417

which is indeed reported to appear again in some newer jQuery versions (jquery 1.8.3 for example)

Maybe try the workaround of replacing `dataType: 'json'` with `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in your ajax options and see if this works for you.

Please see also this thread

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/strange-string-at-the-end-of-my-mesages-jquery15012356981023933311-1302979842877